# Is there an easy way to get directory names without full path in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-facade

I'm trying to get all folder names from a sub folder. I used the following :

```php
$lang = File::directories('resources/lang/');
```

And the result looks like :

```php
[
     "resources/lang/da",
     "resources/lang/de-CH",
     "resources/lang/de-ES",
     "resources/lang/en",
     "resources/lang/en-AE",
     "resources/lang/en-ES",
     "resources/lang/en-GB",
     "resources/lang/en-PT",
     "resources/lang/es",
     "resources/lang/es-PE",
     "resources/lang/fi",
     "resources/lang/fr",
     "resources/lang/fr-CH",
     "resources/lang/fr-ES",
     "resources/lang/it-CH",
     "resources/lang/nl",
     "resources/lang/no",
     "resources/lang/pt",
     "resources/lang/sk",
     "resources/lang/sv",
   ]
```

Is there a way to get only the folder names without the "resources/lang/" part ? (E.g : nl, no, pt, etc.)

Comment: `$partial = explode ("/",$lang);` then to finish `$partial[i][2]`

Comment: You can use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the string to an array, and the last element of the array would be the locale, or [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to strip our `resources/lang`, etc. Have you tried anything? What, specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Just looking for the cleanest solution here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the base directory is always the same, you can use `array_map()` to remove that part.

```php
$lang = array_map(fn($value) => str_replace('resources/lang/', '', $value), $lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array_map** with a standard PHP callback function named **basename** which does exactly that — returns trailing name component of path

```
$lang = array_map('basename', File::directories('resources/lang/'));
```

and the result looks like (works for every path not only `'resource/lang/'`)

```
[
 "da",
 "de-CH",
 "de-ES",
 "en",
 "en-AE",
 "en-ES",
 "en-GB",
 "en-PT",
 "es",
 "es-PE",
 "fi",
 "fr",
 "fr-CH",
 "fr-ES",
 "it-CH",
 "nl",
 "no",
 "pt",
 "sk",
 "sv",
]
```

@see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php